# How to get stack trace for exception occurring in SQL CLR assembly

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclr, clrstoredprocedure

I am trying to use a SQL CLR assembly, but it causes some exception. However, SQL Server Management Studio only says:

```
Msg 10329, Level 16, State 49, Line 7
.Net Framework execution was aborted. 
The statement has been terminated.
```

Is there any way to get the stack trace?

Comment: @MitchWheat - I am not allowed to post it. But I don't see how that's relevant. I am simply asking how to get the stack trace associated with any exception occurring in an SQL CLR assembly.

Comment: It's relevant. Because sharp eyes here might well spot the coding error without a stack trace....

Comment: The SQL server error log should contain a more detailed error.

Comment: Use `try ... catch` *in the CLR code*.

Comment: @MitchWheat - I believe in "Teach a man to fish..."  :-)

Comment: @MitchWheat - Thank you. I will check the log.

Comment: @MitchWheat yes; at the point I added that, the OP had replied to your second comment (I think), but not the all-important 3rd comment; it was mainly intended as a nudge to reinforce that one

Comment: @MarcGravell - I wanted to thank you too, but the comment system would not let me reference more than 1 additional people. Anyway, thanks, I will look at the log.

Comment: @MarcGravell - The error log does not show anything relevant, not even ".Net Framework execution was aborted."

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to retrieve the CLR stack in T-SQL. You have two avenues at your disposal:

1. modify the CLR code, add  `try ... catch ...` block *in the CLR code* and trace the stack to the output from your catch block, using [`SqlPipe.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127319.aspx). This will print the stack as an info message in your T-SQL environment, you can capture it in the client with [`SqlConnection.InfoMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx)
2. Attach debugger to SQL Server and capture *first chance* CLR exceptions (ie. when the exception is raised). This will allow you to troubleshoot the problem and fix it, but obviously is not a solution for production. The SQL Server will *freeze* while stopped under debugger so make sure you do it in a controlled environment.

Answer (score -1):

Calling the CLR directly from SSMS should return the exception and stacktrace, but if it is being called from inside a stored proc then the error message won't be returned. In that case you should use `TRY CATCH` to catch the exception.

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC myproc     
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- insert the error message into a log table here
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE(); 
END CATCH
```